# SAT reading, emerge and begin

Tags: meaning, word-usage, reading

The answer of question 37 is C, but why not B? It "emerged" during 18th century, so obviously, it started developing during that time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The question isn't even grammatical. // I can't see any answer other than B as being correct. Though the specifying definitions of 'human rights as we now understand them' and 'the beginnings of the development of human rights as we now understand them' might generate a few bunfights among academics. For instance, are 'human rights as we now understand them in 2020' the same as 'human rights as the same we  understood them in 2005'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agree. My reason is that the question is talking about the "idea of humanrights" instead of "Universal Declaration". So, apparently, the idea should "emerge" during 18th century instead of beginning "with the adoption of Universal Declaration".

Comment: The clue is in “that the story began in earnest” matching “as we now understand them”.

Comment: This is a very poorly framed question if the answer is to be B. The passage says that the _modern_ notion of human rights _began_ to emerge in the 18th century so the difference between B and C being correct depends on someone's interpretation of 'as we now understand them'. If you think that 'modern' is not synonymous with 'as we now understand them' then you might pick C, if you think that they are synonymous (as I do) then you would pick B.

Comment: @Lawrence - But I would equate “as we now understand them” to “modern notion”

Comment: Not just “modern notion”, but when the modern notion “first began to develop”. “Modern notion” + “began in earnest” excludes A & B, and “first began” excludes D.